# How do i convert csv files that updates weekly to html tables?

Tags: html, csv

I'm new in html.
how do i convert a .csv file into a table to show in html.
conditions.

1. the html needs to extract the .csv content and show it on table form on chrome.
2. the headers are fixed but the data will be updated every week, so html should be able to extract the correct data. only need to update the .csv file.

Comment: You'll need a programming language to do the transformation. HTML is just a markup language.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to insert the data in database and then extract it with php/asp/... then show it in html page.

Comment: @Ashik he may not necessarily need a DB for this if there isn't much manipulations to be done on the data. A simple piece of code to read the .csv and convert it to data rows might do.

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore yes also that can be done with Javascript/Jquery.. :)

Comment: Could you use something like TextFixer.com? See http://www.textfixer.com/html/csv-convert-table.php

Answer (score 0):

either you could do it like Ashik said and switch to a database and load everything via php or another programming language, or you try the direct way. Because of how you asked the question I think you don't have any database or knowledge of other programming languages.

Try to use a javascript library, for example jquery and one of its many plugins to achieve this.

Try this for example: https://code.google.com/p/jquerycsvtotable/

I havn't tried it, but it looks promising, maybe it helps you.

Comment: thanks will look into it later...yes you are right...this is very new to me...i used to do Test Programming for IC. i want to learn new things and this interests me as this will also help in my line of work. many thanks for the suggestion.